# DataTables no se ordena ni filtra solo hace cambio de forma de tablas, Laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

Tengo un problema, con una vista en `laravel` estoy tratando de usar `Datatables` para realizar la paginación y la búsqueda, pero no se muestra la tabla cambiada con los datos, ademas falta la paginación y la búsqueda. Adjunto la vista: `indexEstado.blade.php`

```
  @extends('layouts.principal')
  @section('script')
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
 @stop
 @section('content')
{!! Alert::render() !!}
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
        <h2>Estados</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid tablaLugar">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-0 ">            
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <th id="textoLugar">País</th>
                <th id="textoLugar">Nombre</th>
                <th id="textoLugar">Tipo</th>
                <th id="textoLugar">Ver ciudades</th>
                <th id="textoLugar">Acciones</th>
            </thead>
            @foreach($estado as $lugar)
            <tbody class="well">        
            @if($lugar->tipo=='estado')
                    <td style="display:none;" id="">{{$lugar->idLugar}}</td>
                    @foreach ($pais as $lugar2)
                        @if($lugar->Lugar == $lugar2->idLugar)  
                        <td>{{$lugar2->nombre}}</td>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach                     
                    <td>{{$lugar->nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$lugar->tipo}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Ciudad" id="">
                            <option selected value="">Ciudades de {{$lugar->nombre}}</option>
                                @foreach($ciudad as $lugar3)
                                    @if(($lugar->idLugar == $lugar3->Lugar))
                                        <option value="{{$lugar3->idLugar}}">{{$lugar3->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                        </select>
                    <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('lugar.edit',$lugar->idLugar) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button></a>
                    <a href="{{ route ('eliminarbyIndex', $lugar->idLugar)}}" onclick="return confirm('Estas Seguro de Eliminar el Estado {{$lugar->nombre}}?')"><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
                    </td>                   
                @endif
            </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        <td> <a href = "{{route('agregarEstado')}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" > Nuevo </button> </a> </td>

        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
@section('scriptFooter')
@stop

 @section('DespuesBody')

<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $('.myTable').DataTable({
    });
</script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando tu código esto es lo que veo:

1. El id de tu `<table>` es `myTable` y en el script lo estás capturando como si fuera una clase.
2. La línea donde importas la librería **Datatables** sería mejor que la colocaras el `<head>` de tu sitio
3. Si no vas a configurar la librería si no que la vas a dejar como viene por defecto no es necesario usar `{}` dentro de `()`
4. Tienes varios errores en la estructura de la tabla:

   4.1. Te faltó cerrar un `<td>` en el `<tbody>`

   4.2. La cantidad de columnas debe ser la misma tanto para `<thead>` como para el `<tbody>`. En tu `<thead>` tienes 5 columnas y en tu `<tbody>` tienes 6, a pesar de que una de las 6 columnas está con estilo `display:none` esto podría generar fallos.

   4.3. Estás metiendo la etiqueta `<tbody>` dentro del `foreach()` ... esto debería de ser al contrario.

   4.4. **DataTables** exige que la estructura de la tabla se respete, por lo cual se deben agregar las etiquetas `<tr>` tanto al `<thead>` como al `<tbody>`

Acá te dejo el código como debería de quedar:

```
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Recuerda que esto va en el <head> -->


@extends('layouts.principal')
@section('script')
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
@stop
@section('content')
{!! Alert::render() !!}
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
        <h2>Estados</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid tablaLugar">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-0 ">            
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="textoLugar">País</th>
                    <th id="textoLugar">Nombre</th>
                    <th id="textoLugar">Tipo</th>
                    <th id="textoLugar">Ver ciudades</th>
                    <th id="textoLugar">Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="well">
                @foreach($estado as $lugar)
                    @if($lugar->tipo=='estado')
                        <tr>
                            @foreach ($pais as $lugar2)
                                @if($lugar->Lugar == $lugar2->idLugar)  
                                    <td>{{$lugar2->nombre}}</td>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach                     
                            <td>{{$lugar->nombre}}</td>
                            <td>{{$lugar->tipo}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="Ciudad" id="">
                                    <option selected value="">Ciudades de {{$lugar->nombre}}</option>
                                        @foreach($ciudad as $lugar3)
                                            @if(($lugar->idLugar == $lugar3->Lugar))
                                                <option value="{{$lugar3->idLugar}}">{{$lugar3->nombre}}</option>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ route('lugar.edit',$lugar->idLugar) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button></a>
                                <a href="{{ route ('eliminarbyIndex', $lugar->idLugar)}}" onclick="return confirm('Estas Seguro de Eliminar el Estado {{$lugar->nombre}}?')"><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
                            </td> 
                        </tr>                 
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <td> <a href = "{{route('agregarEstado')}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" > Nuevo </button> </a> </td>

        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
@section('scriptFooter')
@stop

@section('DespuesBody')
<script>
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
</script>
@stop
```

Comment: Gracias por lo del tbody, realicé los cambios mas, no se parece realizar la función script. No se si es que estoy obteniendo el id de manera errónea.

Comment: Si dos:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:5
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ jquery.dataTables.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ jquery.dataTables.min.js:5

Y

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at estados:600
(anonymous) @ estados:600

Comment: Si, ahora el error que sale es:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:89)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:89)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:82)
    at r.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:164)
    at estados:599

Comment: Eliminando el  <td style="display:none;" id="">{{$lugar->idLugar}}</td>, ahora muestra la tabla cambiada y con el buscador, pero no pagina, es decir, solo muestra toda la data en una entrada ademas de que el buscador solo funciona, para la primera fila.

Comment: @AdrianRama usa la versión 1.10.16 tanto para js como para css, veo que en el css usas la versión 1.10.12

Comment: Si ya las cambié: Te muestro los src:

<script src="http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>   <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
<script src="/js/edit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"><script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Listo, realizando los cambios indicados, funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @extends('layouts.principal')
  @section('script')
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script> <!-- Recuerda que esto va en el <head> -->
  @endsection
  @section('content')
   {!! Alert::render() !!}
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <h2>Estados</h2>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid tablaLugar">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-0 ">            
    <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="">País</th>
                <th id="">Nombre</th>
                <th id="">Tipo</th>
                <th id="">Ver ciudades</th>
                <th id="">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th id="">País</th>
                <th id="">Nombre</th>
                <th id="">Tipo</th>
                <th id="">Ver ciudades</th>
                <th id="">Acciones</th>
            </tr>           
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($estado as $lugar)
                <tr>
                    @foreach($pais as $lugar2)
                        @if($lugar->Lugar == $lugar2->idLugar)  
                            <td>{{$lugar2->nombre}}</td>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                    <td>{{$lugar->nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$lugar->tipo}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Ciudad" id="">
                            <option selected value="">Ciudades de {{$lugar->nombre}}</option>
                                @foreach($ciudad as $lugar3)
                                    @if(($lugar->idLugar == $lugar3->Lugar))
                                        <option value="{{$lugar3->idLugar}}">{{$lugar3->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('lugar.edit',$lugar->idLugar) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button></a>
                    <a href="{{ route ('eliminarbyIndex', $lugar->idLugar)}}" onclick="return confirm('Estas Seguro de Eliminar el Estado {{$lugar->nombre}}?')"><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <td> <a href = "{{route('agregarEstado')}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" > Nuevo </button> </a> </td>

    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('scriptFooter')
@endsection

@section('DespuesBody')
 <script>
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
 </script>
@endsection
```